# Attaching files in VSIX container

Tags: resources, visual-studio-2013, vs-extensibility

Is it possible to include some predefined files in the VSIX container and then access them by the extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .vsixmanifest designer select Assets - New - Select type and file name. Or directly edit .vsixmanifest Assets node. These files will be deployed to the same directory as the main extension dll.

Comment: Cool! One more question: is there a way to get the path of extension directory other than `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` ?

Comment: I don't know an other way and personally use GetExecutingAssembly().Location too.

Comment: It's even simpler :) There's an option "Include in VSIX" in Properties Pane (or maybe it appears after adding a file to manifest?)

Comment: @Spook,  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)   after 8 years :)

Answer (score 5):

In Solution Explorer, right click the file and open Properties pane.

Set `Include in VSIX` = `true`

[image: Include in VSIX]